# Java static variable access

Tags: java, static, static-methods

can somebody please explain me why left code is possible to complile, but the second one no? I think that in both cases I am trying to access same "number" variable, but I am probably wrong... Thanks for explanation.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8kNx.png)

Comment: There is no `this` in a static method

Comment: For the code on the right, the method is static. That means, the static method it is shared between all instances. Being static/shared, it cannot access an instance variable (this.number)

Comment: thanks for fast answer. I thought that this in static method is class by itself (this.number == Number.number)

Comment: @RadekChromík You've got it backwards. You can access a static field in a non-static context using (e.g.) `this.number`, but you cannot use `this` in a static context, even to refer to a static field.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first understand what is static method and how it works, then we can easily conclude the answer of this question.

Whenever a method is declared as static then we should keep in mind these points:

A static method belongs to the class rather than object of a class.
A static method can be invoked without the need for creating an instance of a class.
static method can access static data member and can change the value of it.

Now, this keyword in java is a reference variable that refers to the current object. Also the super keyword in java is a reference variable which is used to refer immediate parent class object.

So, we can say that this and super both keywords are reference variable that refers to some object. In other words these both keywords belong to instance of the class.

Whereas, static member belongs to the class than instance of the class. And so static member can’t access this and super keyword in java.